# Calculating distance between angles that cross -180 to 180

Tags: python, angle

I am calculating the difference, in degrees, between my mouse pointer's angle in relation to my 'vehicle's angle. I take half that distance, which I store as my offset, then move my vehicle to it, which after a few calculations, eventually moves me to my desired angle. However, when my mouse is at -185, and I move it slightly up to 185, which is only 10 degrees away, the vehicle takes the "long way around", traveling from -185, to 0, then back up to 185. I have tried many ways to let it be able to pass the -180 to 180 boundary, but had no luck.

Heres the code:

```
def get_angle(self, p1, p2):
    return m.atan2(p2[1]-p1[1],p2[0]-p1[0])

def update(self):
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    self.update_vehicle(self.pos, self.get_angle(self.pos, mouse_pos), r.black)

def update_vehicle(self, pos, dir, color):
    self.dir += (dir - self.dir) / 50
```

where `self.dir` is the angle my vehicle realises, and `dir` is the angle passed to it, from the mouse to itself.

Comment: would you be willing to share the code snipped which illustrates the described problem?

Comment: @Ivan There you go. That's the functional part, I wouldn't think you need the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the output angle into the [-pi, pi) interval  before applying it to the car:

```
def update_vehicle(self, pos, dir, color):
    a = ((dir - self.dir + m.pi) % (2 * m.pi)) - m.pi
    self.dir += a / 50
```

What is happening is that we add pi to the value (so that we aim at a positive 0 to 2pi interval), then we remove useless complete turns (with mod 2pi) and finally get back to our initial -pi to pi reference (removing the pi we had inserted before).

As a consequence, -400º turns into -40º, -240º into 120º, 240º into -120º and so on... here is a small list of examples:

```
-400°  ->   -40°
-320°  ->    40°
-240°  ->   120°
-160°  ->  -160°
 -80°  ->   -80°
   0°  ->     0°
  80°  ->    80°
 160°  ->   160°
 240°  ->  -120°
 320°  ->   -40°
 400°  ->    40°
```

I'm supposing `m` is the native `math` module, by the way.

Comment: I tried that, but I am not seeing any change in behavior. I understand what you are saying, and I see how it would work, but I can't figure out why it won't.

Comment: @BrrrIce, the wrap should be done with the final angle you want to apply to the car. I've edited my solution accordingly and it did work with your code.